# hide element if it doesn't match v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

What I'm doing is kind of like a search by tag system. I'm using vuetify 1.0.19 right now to do chips. The tags' v-model is an array. Now, If it doesn't match the chips in the card ([Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZXCX.jpg)), I want to hide that card. I kind of want to do jQuery's `.find()` then `.hide()` functions but I don't want to use jQuery cause' I'm learning vue right now. I do know how to do this in jQuery and simulate it in the `methods` section of the script. But doing that looks dirty so I'm just asking If there is a more efficient way of doing this.

tags

```
<v-select
  v-model="tags"
  label="Search Tags"
  prepend-icon="label"
  chips
  tags
  @input="hideCard()"
></v-select>
```

cards (it's inside a v-for because it comes from the database. I'm using nuxt to render this cards)

```
<v-flex xs2 v-for="(event, index) in events" :key="index" class="hide-me">
  <v-card hover ripple :to="`/event/${event.idevents}`">
    <v-card-title>
      <h2>{{ event.idevents + ' - ' + event.eventname }}</h2>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <div class="subheading">Organizer/s:</div>
      <v-chip v-for="(organizer, i) in JSON.parse(event.managedBy)" :key="i">{{ organizer.toUpperCase() }}</v-chip>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-flex>
```

script

```
export default {
  async asyncData () {
    let data = await axios.get('/events')
    let dbTags = await axios.get('/tags')
    let tagnames = []
    for (let i = 0; i < dbTags.data.length; i++) {
      tagnames.push(dbTags.data[i].tagname)
    }
    return {
      events: data.data,
      savedTags: tagnames,
      tags: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideCard () {
      document.querySelectorAll('.hide-me').forEach(elm => {
        if (this.tags.length > 0) {
          this.tags.forEach(tag => {
            console.log(elm.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(tag.toLowerCase()) > -1)
            if (!(elm.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(tag.toLowerCase()) > -1)) {
              elm.classList.add('hide')
            } else {
              elm.classList.remove('hide')
            }
          })
        } else {
          elm.classList.remove('hide')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: edit your Question and post your code so we can see what you got?

Comment: hints: v-if, computed properties